# Popup close event in jxbrowser

Tags: popupwindow, jxbrowser

I implemented a popup handler for jxbrowser 6.0.

Is there any way for the popup to send (event) to main browser that it (the popup) was closed?

The main browser must suspend this activity until the opened popup is closed.

Answer (score 0):

To find out when popup is closed use the following approach:

```
browser.setPopupHandler(new PopupHandler() {
    public PopupContainer handlePopup(PopupParams params) {
        return new PopupContainer() {
            public void insertBrowser(final Browser browser, final Rectangle initialBounds) {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        BrowserView popupView = new BrowserView(browser);
                        popupView.setPreferredSize(initialBounds.getSize());

                        final JFrame popupFrame = new JFrame("Popup");
                        popupFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                        popupFrame.add(popupView, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                        popupFrame.pack();
                        popupFrame.setLocation(initialBounds.getLocation());
                        popupFrame.setVisible(true);
                        popupFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                            @Override
                            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                                browser.dispose();
                            }
                        });

                        browser.addDisposeListener(new DisposeListener<Browser>() {
                            public void onDisposed(DisposeEvent<Browser> event) {
                                popupFrame.setVisible(false);
                                // Notify parent that popup has been closed.
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,
In the parent browser what is the code to monitor the popup closure?

Thanks Vladimir.

Comment: I have already provided this code. The "browser" instance is a parent browser instance.

Answer (score 0):

I had already found a running solution with boolean variable, but i should want a more elegant one.

```
            browser.addDisposeListener(new DisposeListener() {
                public void onDisposed(DisposeEvent event) {
                    finestraAComparsa.setVisible(false);
                    Automazione.finestraAComparsaChiusa = true;//
                    // Notify parent that popup has been closed.
                }
            });
```

In the main browser class file:

```
                try {
                    while (!finestraAComparsaChiusa) {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }
                    finestraAComparsaChiusa = false;
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
```